# Function returns Future<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm learning flutter and I have a function which returns a UserLocation object -

```
getUserLocation() async {
    bool _serviceEnabled;
    loc.PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }
    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == loc.PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != loc.PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    try {
      _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    List<geo.Placemark> placemarks = await geo.placemarkFromCoordinates(
        _currentPosition.latitude ?? 0, _currentPosition.longitude ?? 0);

    var countryNameList = placemarks[0].country?.split(' ');

    if (countryNameList!.isNotEmpty && countryNameList.length >= 2) {
      for (var eachLetter in countryNameList) {
        abbr += eachLetter[0];
      }
    } else {
      abbr = countryNameList.toString().substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
    }
    return UserLocation(
        city: placemarks[0].locality ?? 'Chennai',
        country: abbr,
        latitude: _currentPosition.latitude,
        longitude: _currentPosition.longitude);
  }
```

Now, when I'm calling this function, It says that It returns Future<dynamic)..Future because it's an async function and dynamic because it doesn't really return anything if location.ServiceEnabled or location.hasPermission fails.

Anyways, the point is that I want to access the UserLocation object returned by this method whenever I'm calling this function from somewhere else but It always say that this function returns Future. How I can do that?? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem, Set the return type of `getUserLocation()` function to `Future<UserLocation?>` and return null wherever there is nothing to return.